# Help in understanding pointfree code

Tags: haskell, pointfree

When playing around with [Pointfree](https://github.com/benmachine/pointfree%20Pointfree) I was presented with a piece of code that I can't seem to understand.

```
:pl map (\x -> x * x) [1..10]
-- map (join (*)) [1..10]
```

My main problem is that I don't get how `join` works here. I understand that it 'removes' one layer of a monadic wrapping (`m (m a)` to `m a`). I figure it boils down to something like `[1..10] >>= (\x -> [x * x])`, but I don't really get how the "extra layer" gets introduced. I get that `join x = x >>= id`, but then I'm still stuck on how that "duplicates" each value so that `(*)` gets two arguments. This has been bugging me for about half an hour now and I'm mostly annoyed at myself, because I feel like I have all the puzzle pieces but can't seem to fit them together...

P.S. Don't worry, I would't really use this pointfree version, this is pure curiosity and an attempt to understand Haskell better.

Comment: `join :: m (m a) -> m a` doesn't exactly "remove" a layer of monadic wrapping, it's much more accurate to say it squishes two layers into one. Hence the name, indeed...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`join` is using the instance of `Monad` for `(->) a`, as defined in `Control.Monad.Instances`. The instance is similar to `Reader`, but without an explicit wrapper. It is defined like this:

```
instance Monad ((->) a) where
  -- return :: b -> (a -> b)
  return = const
  -- (>>=) :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> c)
  f >>= g = \x -> g (f x) x
```

If you now reduce `join` using this instance:

```
join
(>>= id)
flip (\f g x -> g (f x) x) (\a -> a)
(\f x -> (\a -> a) (f x) x)
(\f x -> f x x)
```

As you can see, the instance for `(->) a` makes `join` to a function that applies an argument twice. Because of this, `join (*)` is simply `\x -> x * x`.

Comment: Sh*t. Thank you. I am apparently too tired.

Comment: You can also work this out from parametricity. In the monad `(->) a`, `join` has the type `((->) a) ((->) a b) -> ((->) a b)`, which simplifies to `(a -> a -> b) -> a -> b`. It's clear that the only thing `join` can do to get a `b` is feed the `a` to the function twice. (Apart from using bottom values, of course).

Comment: @hammar Wasn't there a program that could figure out a function's only sensible definition by looking at the type signature? (If possible)

Comment: @FUZxxl: Yes, [Djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn). The package seems to be slightly out of date, though.

Comment: @FUZxxl: It's called Djinn; while I found [the announcement on Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1178), the darcs repository seems to be down.

Comment: Djinn is also built into lambdabot on the #haskell IRC channel... though lambdabot seems to be mysteriously MIA right at this moment.

Comment: I've uploaded a new version of Djinn.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was missing! :-) I actually played around with the monad instance of `((->) a)` a bit but didn't get anywhere, probably because it was approaching 2am here and I was pretty tired. Thanks again!

Comment: There you go, I had only accepted so far, not upvoted (by mistake).